# How to implementing angular-formly template for custom ui/css library?

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I want to implementing angular-formly custom template for my application. I don't want to use bootstrap template because I have a custom UI/css library. How do I implement custom template? Do I get angular-formly-templates-vanilla or angular-formly-templates-bootstrap and customize it to my need. Currently I am implementing template using separate html files as below but I want to reuse template so is this the best solution?

```
  angular
        .module('myApp').run(function(formlyConfig) {
      formlyConfig.setType([{
        name: 'input',
        templateUrl: 'input.html',
        overwriteOk: true
      },
      {
        name: 'select',
        templateUrl: 'select.html',
        overwriteOk: true
      }]);
    });
```

Html document

input.html

```
<div class="custom-group">
   <label class="form-label" for="{{options.key}}">
   {{to.label}}
   </label>
   <input id="{{options.key}}" ng-model="model[options.key]" type="text">
</div>
```

select.html

```
<div class="custom-group">
   <label class="form-label" for="{{options.key}}">{{to.label}}</label>
   <span class="form-select-span">
   <select class="form-control" id="{{options.key}}" ng-model="model[options.key]"
      ng-options="option.value as option.name group by option.group for option in options.templateOptions.options">
   </select>
   </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply give it a className and then just overwrite the CSS?
You are attempting to re-invent the wheel when it doesn't need to be done.